# send input file with special characters (such as accents) to the web server

Tags: html, iis, asp-classic

I´m working with asp classic and using IIS like web server.
i have to send files (using input files) from the html web page.
The problem is when i have special caracteres in the files´ name.
For example: when the file´s name is "Distribución de tareas para desarrollo.docx" and the name reaches the server like "DistribuciÃ³n de tareas para desarrollo.docx"
Here is my html head code.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I try to work with the charset in the html code and the asp code but it´s does´t work.

Now add these lines as suggested by the user @Daniel Nordh.

```
`
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
 <% Response.CodePage = 65001
    Response.CharSet = "UTF-8" 
 %>
```

`
But, the result is the same.

Well it seems that I am facing the issue badly.
I know that when sending input file from the browser, the data arrives with binary files.
Once I separate the header I see that the file reaches the server it does as follows.

-----------------------------7e33a72830078c Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc"; filename="DistribuciÃ³n de tareas para desarrollo.docx" Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document PK

And reading the name is the same way I get.

But if I write the following code on the same page asp.

```
response.write "<br>panificación<br>"
```

When requesting the page is displayed.
panificación.

What I am thinking about is that I have the problem because it is input files that are sent as binary files.

HTML form to send the files.

```html
<form  method="post" action="files.asp" target="_blank" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="group-form">
       <div class="input-group">
              <input accept=".doc,.docx" type="file" name="archivo">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"  >doc (opcional)</span>
      </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Here the code that processes the files received.
The variables and comments are in Spanish.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%    
    Response.CodePage = 65001
    Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
%>    
<%

dim v_recordset
dim v_arreglo_archivos
dim v_archivo 
dim v_bytes
dim v_posicion_limite
dim v_datos_binarios
dim v_longitud_binaria
dim v_agregar_lvc
dim v_datos_completos
dim v_inicio_archivo
dim v_final_archivo
dim v_cadena_delimitadora
dim v_datos_archivo
dim v_inicio_nombre
dim v_fin_nombre
dim v_cadena_nombre_archivo
dim v_pos_temp
dim v_pos_previa
dim v_nombre_archivo
dim v_content_type
dim v_inicio_datos
dim v_fin_datos
dim v_longitud_datos
dim v_file_object
dim v_creador_archivos
dim v_datos_enviados
dim v_cantidad_archivos_subidos
dim v_bandera_archivo_lleno


set v_recordset=CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

on error resume next

v_agregar_lvc=201
v_cantidad_archivos_subidos=0


v_bytes=request.totalBytes
v_datos_binarios=request.BinaryRead(v_bytes)
v_longitud_binaria=LenB(v_datos_binarios)

if v_longitud_binaria>0 then
    v_recordset.Fields.Append "mi_binario",v_agregar_lvc,v_longitud_binaria
    v_recordset.Open 
    v_recordset.AddNew
    v_recordset("mi_binario").AppendChunk v_datos_binarios
    v_recordset.Update 
    v_datos_completos=v_recordset("mi_binario")
end if

v_encabezado=request.ServerVariables("HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE")
v_posicion_limite=instr(1,v_encabezado,"boundary=") + 8

 v_cadena_delimitadora= right(v_encabezado,len(v_encabezado)- v_posicion_limite)  

v_cadena_delimitadora="--" &v_cadena_delimitadora 

v_inicio_archivo=instr(1,v_datos_completos,v_cadena_delimitadora)



 v_final_archivo=instr(v_inicio_archivo+1,v_datos_completos,
 v_cadena_delimitadora)-1




  do while v_final_archivo>0



    v_datos_archivo=mid(v_datos_completos,v_inicio_archivo,v_final_archivo - 
    v_inicio_archivo)

    v_inicio_nombre=instr(1,v_datos_archivo,"filename=")+10
    v_fin_nombre=instr(v_inicio_nombre,v_datos_archivo,chr(34))

    v_datos_completos=replace(v_datos_completos,v_datos_archivo,"")


    if v_inicio_nombre=v_fin_nombre then


        v_bandera_archivo_lleno=false

        do while not v_bandera_archivo_lleno

           v_inicio_archivo=instr(1,v_datos_completos,
                            v_cadena_delimitadora)
           v_final_archivo=instr(v_inicio_archivo+1,v_datos_completos,
                            v_cadena_delimitadora)-1    

           v_datos_archivo=mid(v_datos_completos,v_inicio_archivo,
                           v_final_archivo - v_inicio_archivo)

           v_inicio_nombre=instr(1,v_datos_archivo,"filename=")+10
           v_fin_nombre=instr(v_inicio_nombre,v_datos_archivo,chr(34))



            if v_inicio_nombre<>v_fin_nombre then
                v_bandera_archivo_lleno=true
            end if

            v_datos_completos=replace(v_datos_completos,v_datos_archivo,"")

        loop    

    end if





     if v_inicio_nombre<>v_fin_nombre then



     v_cadena_nombre_archivo=mid(v_datos_archivo,v_inicio_nombre,
                                v_fin_nombre - v_inicio_nombre)
     v_pos_temp=instr(1,v_cadena_nombre_archivo,"\")

        do while v_pos_temp>0

            v_pos_previa=v_pos_temp
            v_pos_temp=instr(v_pos_previa+1,v_cadena_nombre_archivo,"\")
        loop

        v_nombre_archivo=right(v_cadena_nombre_archivo,
                        len(v_cadena_nombre_archivo) - v_pos_temp)

        v_content_type=instr(1,v_datos_archivo,"Content-type:")


        if v_content_type>0 then
        v_inicio_datos=instr(v_content_type,v_datos_archivo,chr(13)&chr(10)) 
                        + 4
        else
            v_inicio_datos=v_fin_nombre
        end if

        v_fin_datos=len(v_datos_archivo)


        v_longitud_datos=v_fin_datos - v_inicio_datos
        v_datos_enviados=mid(v_datos_archivo,v_inicio_datos,v_fin_datos)


    end if

    v_inicio_archivo=instr(1,v_datos_completos,v_cadena_delimitadora)
    v_final_archivo=instr(v_inicio_archivo+1,v_datos_completos,
                    v_cadena_delimitadora)-1

loop
```

okay. Once the content is obtained it is saved on the server. But that is something else that is not causing me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save your files as UTF-8 as well. Try adding this to the very top of the page(s) you're working with. Encoding and ASP Classic can be a nightmare from my own experience.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
response.codepage = 65001
response.charset = "utf-8"
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for comments. I put the lines you told me and save the files in utf-8 encoding but I am getting the same.

Comment: What's the code to send the file to the server? Btw, as a rule I try to keep filenames to [a-z][0-9], "-" and "_". I suppose it's less of an issue nowadays, but back in the old days it was way more problematic working with files that had other symbols in them.

Comment: The files are uploaded by external users since it is a web system. We recommend without accents and without blanks but there is always the user who does not follow the recommendation. 
The code to send the file to the server?
It's an html form if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm not a regex-expert, but you can limit names to a specific set of characters, preventing them to be sent unless named properly. And yes, it could be useful to see the form and any script that may be involved in the sending. Also, does it send via a helper-file? I tend to keep functions for pages in a separate file. Both would have to use the code above to work correctly.

Comment: I would rather avoid changing the name from javascript. But if there is no other alternative I will have to do so.

Comment: When the server is received, it is an auxiliary file.
I found the code to process the files on the web and it is very practical.
I will attach it to you despite being long.

Comment: You need to add the above code, and save "files.asp" as UTF-8 as well. If that's the file that's processing the transfer, that's probably where the problem occurs.

Comment: The UTF-8 header is incorporated and also the file is saved with the UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I think I will have to work the names from Javascript because I can't find a solution.
If I write response.write "Panificación"
It is shown as Panificación. So I assume that the problem is the files sent and not the encoding of the files.asp